# C# .NET logging screen activity on a server for a given user

Tags: c#, .net, windows-services, keylogger

I'm looking into writing a windows service (.NET) that can run on a windows server (2008) preferably hidden, and I basically want it to do the following:

1. Check upon logon the current user
2. If the user is "SpecificUsername" start logging screen activity (can be screen shots every second or so  or video)
3. If no keyboard presses / mouse click are detected within a time period pause recording
4. Upon the user logging off stop capture

My question is:

Can I capture the screen using .NET natively or is there a recommended third party dll I could use for this?

Comment: please elaborate since the answer depends on the sophistication of your user and whether this should be detectable/hidden/defend itself against termination by that user etc. - the possible solutions range from a simple .NET application (started by the user's LogonScript) to a rootkit-like kernel-mode device driver...

Comment: Your question is very broad and essentially boils down to "How do I write my program?" you have identified 4 different requirements / challenges - I suggest that you [have a go](http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/) and post questions about  **specific** problems you are having.

Comment: Fair comments I will update the question now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[This link](http://www.developerfusion.com/code/4630/capture-a-screen-shot/) takes you to some good code for screen capture in c#. I was thinking of using this but haven't got around to the app that uses it.

Checking the current user can be done within the application most easy depending on where you save the logon information ie: session, windows auth, cookies or database etc.